# Fragment constraint layout stretching on top of tabs of the main activity

Tags: android, constraints, android-tabs, android-constraintlayout

I've built a Fragment with constraint layout with a `ListView`, empty view and a total count view. The bottom constraint is working (with an artificial adjustment though), but the top is overlapping the tabs from my `MainActivity`:

[image]

My code is here and it's my first time using constraint layout:

```
{ 
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/total_items_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total_items_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrange"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="Items in this category: "
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/items_number_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/items_number_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrange"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="44"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/total_items_view" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/empty_book_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/orange_orange_book" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_title_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/empty_book_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="This category is still empty..."
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_subtitle_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/empty_title_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Let's start with adding books!"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#A2AAB0" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout> 
}
```

Is there any way to set a constraint to a view in a separate (main) activity? How can I fix this?

I have tried the `wrap_content`, and the only thing I can think of is manually setting it a little bit off the top, which kind of ruins the concept of constraint layout.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue was outside ConstraintLayout: ViewPager and TabLayout were mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply constraint outside constraint layout. The problem is with parent layout, it seems like your view pager is overlapping tab layout.

Comment: That's true! The constraint layout had nothing to do with it - it was a silly mistake with ViewPager and TabsLayout placement. ConstraintLayout does seem to rock after all :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not use `match_parent` in ConstraintLayout, just eg. if you want to make view match screen width use

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

The thing why it overlapping is that you probably do not limit top of your list (or list container) to bottom of this top view like

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_view"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView's` height is set to `wrap_content` in which case it will expand as much as it needs to and overlap other views. If you want to use `wrap_content` and enforce the constraints of the view at the same time, you need to add `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` attribute to to your `ListView`.